# Sharepoint Online and refreshing excel files.

Tags: sharepoint, office365, excel-2013, sharepoint-online

Is there a way to have all excel files in a list to auto refresh their sources once a day? If not is there a way to add code to do this?

Comment: what do the "refresh" mean? just change the last modified time?

Comment: If there is linked data. To update the excel for any modified data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way. You can use Refresh on open or periodic refresh:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-server-help/refresh-external-data-in-excel-services-HA010105474.aspx

Have a look also at these threads:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45549/excel-web-part-from-list-autorefresh
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/258013dc-2687-486c-8d87-3834e25bf0f4/how-to-autorefresh-pivot-table-in-excel-web-access-webpart-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Check also the supported connections and scenarios:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-help/work-with-external-data-in-excel-services-sharepoint-server-HA102830785.aspx